# Changing userforms control name using microsoft visual basic for applications extensibility 5.3 error "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

There is 4 userforms with multiple controls in my project.

1. UserForm1(ctrl1,ctrl2,ctrl3,ctrl4),
2. UserForm2(ctrl1,ctrl2,ctrl3,ctrl4),
3. UserForm3(ctrl1,ctrl2,ctrl3,ctrl4),
4. UserForm4(ctrl1,ctrl2,ctrl3,ctrl4)

I want to change all controls name for all userforms using microsoft visual basic for applications extensibility 5.3.

After changing the controls name in 1st user form when it goes to change the control name in 2nd user form it gives me error " Run time error - 91  Object variable or With block variable not set"

Here is my code

```
Dim ctrl As Object
Dim arr(3) As String
Dim ctrlArr(3) As String
Dim item As variant
Dim item2 As variant
Dim vComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim nameArr(15) As String
Dim i As Integer

'Setting userforms name in array
arr(0)="UserForm1"
arr(1)="UserForm2"
arr(2)="UserForm3"
arr(3)="UserForm4"

'Setting Controls name in array
ctrlArr(0)="ctrl1"
ctrlArr(1)="ctrl2"    
ctrlArr(2)="ctrl3"
ctrlArr(3)="ctrl4"

'Setting controls name array
nameArr(0) = "name1"
nameArr(1) = "name2"
....
....
....
nameArr(15) = "name16"

i = 0


'Looping through userforms array
For Each item In arr
    Set vComp = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(item)
    'Looping through our controls array
    For Each item2 in ctrlArr
        Set ctrl = vComp.Designer.Controls(item2) 'Error occured in this line
        ctrl.name = nameArr(i)
        i=i+1
    next item2
Next item
```

The above code changes all controls name in 1st user form fine but show error when going to change 2nd userform control name.

Please help.

Comment: Which exact line is the error on?

Comment: I have marked the line where the error occured. I have debugged my code and found that 1st time when the code run 'Set vComp = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(item)' this line create a designer object and all the controls name are there but when going set the second userform, there is nothing in designer object. So the code failed to change the name of the control.But why the same line of code work for one userform and not for other userform?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got a solution of my problem....
Actually, there is no problem in the above code. The problem is in the userform code. My 2nd userform has a control which is connected to a class module to filter it data whenever user type something. After commenting out the code of the class module in the userform. Everything working fine. But i don't know why this problem happening because i have another userform with another class connected to it. I think there is some problem in the filtering class coding.